# C# getting first Characters of a file name

Tags: c#, string, directory

I have a directory name "C:\Folder\160_Name_2013111914447.7z" what I need is to extract the "160" from the file name in C# and use it to pass it to a MS-SQL method so I can move the file to a correct file Namely "160".

Please help, as I'm kinda new to C#.

Comment: Do you want to get first `3` character in your file name? Or from start to first `_` character? That's the your pattern?

Comment: @SonerGönül The file name will not usually have 3 characters. It might be first 4 or 6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Folder\160_Name_2013111914447.7z").Split('_')[0];
```

Or possibly

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Folder\160_Name_2013111914447.7z");
Regex.Match(fileName, "^([0-9]+)_").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to take the first 3 symbols, you can use the [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)  method of the `string` class:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Folder\160_Name_2013111914447.7z");
// take 3 symbols starting from 0th character.
string extracted = fileName.Substring(0, 3);
```

If you can have variable length of key characters and the underscore character is the separator, then we'll have to modify the above code a little. First, we'll need the index of the underscore:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Folder\160_Name_2013111914447.7z");

// get the zero-based index of the first occurrence of an underscore:
int underscoreIndex = fileName.IndexOf("_");
```

The [`string.IndexOf(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) methods returns `-1` if match is not found, so we need to check for it.

```
if (underscoreIndex >= 0)
{
    string extracted = fileName.Substring(0, underscoreIndex); 
}
else
{
     // no underscore found
     throw new InvalidOperationException(
         "Cannot extract data from file name: " + fileName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this will work in this case, Because the number of the first characters will not always be 3. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

To get the number assuming the file path you input will always be at the start and a length of 3 characters you can use.

```
       FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

        string name = fileInfo .Name;

       int startingNumber = Convert.ToInt32(name.Substring(0,3));
```

where path is the full path of the file your using